# Unable to click/tap an element in the android real device . Once launch appium server getting exitted and throws noclassdeffound error

Tags: android, selenium, appium

I'm using appium on selenium java to do mobile test automation. The below code is to create desired capabilities

base.java file has below codings

```
import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobilePlatform;

public class base {

    public static AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> capabilities () throws MalformedURLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver;
        
        //AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver;
        File appDir = new File("src");
        File app = new File(appDir,"GooiGooi App.apk");
        
        DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
        //cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "db48f8d9");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Android Device");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, app.getAbsolutePath());
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, "uiautomator2");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME,MobilePlatform.ANDROID );
         driver = new  AndroidDriver<>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),cap);
        
        return driver;
    }
```

basics that extends base has following code

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement;

public class basics extends base {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        
        AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver = capabilities();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        //xpath, resoruceid, class name, androiduiautomator
        
        //xpath syntax //tagName[@attribute='value']
```

`
driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.EditText[@text='Phone number']").sendKeys("1234567890");

```
    }

}

}
```

I also have the following dependencies in pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
        <version>7.6.0</version>
    </dependency>

 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>
    



    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.14.0</version>
</dependency>


</dependencies>
```

---

While executing this script, I get the following error console message as

Before launch1

```
Mar 06, 2022 1:20:17 AM io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1 lambda$0
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
AFter launch
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Coordinates
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Unknown Source)
    at io.appium.java_client.internal.JsonToMobileElementConverter.newRemoteWebElement(JsonToMobileElementConverter.java:72)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.JsonToWebElementConverter.apply(JsonToWebElementConverter.java:55)
    at io.appium.java_client.internal.JsonToMobileElementConverter.apply(JsonToMobileElementConverter.java:63)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:561)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:41)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:323)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.findElement(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:61)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.findElement(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.findElement(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:428)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.findElementByXPath(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:151)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.findElementByXPath(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.findElementByXPath(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at TestElement.main(TestElement.java:18)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Coordinates
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 20 more
```

Can I know what would have caused this issue pls?

Comment: App is getting launched but not clicking on any of the links displayed on page after launch.

Answer (score 0):

Appium has certain requirement to start/launch any app from your device .
Since you are using app from certain file, but you also need to provide appActivity caps in order to start first screen from your app. Just app that caps .

```
 {  "deviceName": "<Your device Name>",
  "platformVersion": "<Android Platform version>",
  "platformName": "Android",
  "appActivity": "<Your activity Name>",
  "automationName": "UiAutomator2",
}
```

Comment: App is launching in appium, but click or sendkeys on any object returns the following error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Coordinates
 at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Unknown Source)
 at io.appium.java_client.internal.JsonToMobileElementConverter.newRemoteWebElement(JsonToMobileElementConverter.java:72)